# How to show the two grid in single page?

Tags: magento-1.9, grid, product-grid

I am working vendor concept site.

Here I am using two types of products:

> 1. My Uploaded Products (My Own Products).
> 2. Assigned Products (Assign the Other vendor Products to my product).

In the admin-panel under catalog need to add one sub menu "My All Products" (I did this).

Once click this sub-menu, need to show the both my uploaded products and assign products in the tab view.

When I click my uploaded products tab to show all my uploaded products in that grid.

Then I click assign products tab to show all assign products in that grid.

[image]

How can i do this ?.

Please any one help me.